# How to add Google Tag Manager or Google Analytics to Quasar SSR app?

Tags: google-analytics, quasar

I've added Google Analytics script to index.template.html and I get the first page that user enters logged by Google Analytics, but the following pages are not logged. I've tried Quasar Meta Plugin, but don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution!

Followed those instructions: https://jannerantala.com/tutorials/quasar-framework-google-tag-manager-and-analytics-setup-for-an-spa-website/

with the following modifications for SSR:
1. instead src/plugins/gtm-plugin.js I created src/boot/gtmplugin.js
2. in quasar.conf.js instead

> plugins: [
>       ...
>       'gtmplugin']

I added:

> boot: [
>         ... { path: 'gmtplugin', server: false }]

Comment: `with the following modifications for SSR` - Note: This isn't a change because of SSR, this is a requirement of v1.0. Plugins are no longer user plugins, the boot files are for that.

Comment: That's right - to be more specific point 2 indicates the SSR modification.